# How to configure ProtonVPN

Tags: command-line, networking, network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I just installed OpenVPN and ProtonVPN but missed something, I followed the command line installation on ProtonVPN site and it says I am connected when attempting to initalize but does not change my IPv4. I am pretty new to Linux based OS's but can get it for the most part but am stuck. I suspect I need to edit a file in OpenVPN with ProtonVPN info, but don't want to mess anything up any help would be much appreciated. If you need more info from my terminal please let me know thanks! It's not running and when I attempt to initialize it returns:

```
:/$ sudo protonvpn-cli --init
[!] User profile for protonvpn-cli has already been initialized. Would you like to start over with a fresh configuration? [Y/n]: 

Checking the status returns:
protonvpn-cli --status
[OpenVPN Status]: Running
[ProtonVPN Status]: Not Running
[Internet Status]: Online
[Public IP Address]: 00.000.000.0 (edited for privacy but returns accurate public IP)
```

I followed the link below:

https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-tool/

Comment: protonvpn-cli --status
[OpenVPN Status]: Running
[ProtonVPN Status]: Not Running
[Internet Status]: Online
[Public IP Address]: 00.000.000.0 (edited for privacy but returns accurate public IP)

Comment: It looks like you've skipped the username/password step, the plan selection step, the connection step, the server selection step, and so on. There is no mention of having to "edit a file in OpenVPN with ProtonVPN info", so no reason to suspect it.

Comment: @mikewhatever Hey no sorry I just didn't post that. I followed the instructions completely so that's why i'm so confused. I'll post what my terminal is still showing after going back through the steps again thanks.

Comment: ~$ sudo protonvpn-cli -init
[!] User profile for protonvpn-cli has already been initialized. Would you like to start over with a fresh configuration? [Y/n]: y
Enter OpenVPN username: ************************
Enter OpenVPN password:

Comment: [.] ProtonVPN Plans:
1) Free
2) Basic
3) Plus
4) Visionary
Enter Your ProtonVPN plan ID: 1
[.] Would you like to use a custom DNS server? (Warning: This would make your VPN connection vulnerable to DNS leaks. Only use it when you know what you're doing) [y/N]: n
[.] [Security] Decrease OpenVPN privileges? [Y/n]: y
[*] Done.
fuzzywuzza@FuzzyWuzzaG:~$ protonvpn-cli -status
[OpenVPN Status]: Not Running
[ProtonVPN Status]: Not Running
Internet Status]: Online
[Public IP Address]: 00.000.000.0

Comment: And thanks for editing I am new here and cant get my post to display that way instead of all jumbled up i'll look around and try to figure it out.